# Нетипичный выход из switch и for: выход из нескольких вложенных блоков и циклов

Tags: c++, c

Как, находясь в `switch(b)`, выйти сразу из `switch(a)` (`switch(b)` находится внутри `case` в `а`), при этом не выходя из функции `с`, в которой они находятся?

```
void c()
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case 1:
            switch (b)
            {
                case 1:
                    ???
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

И ещё вопрос - как, находясь в цикле, который находится в `switch`, выйти сразу из `switch`, не выходя из функции (и наоборот - если `switch` находится в `for`)?

```
void c()
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case 1:
            for (;;)
            {
                ???
            }
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

**`goto` не принимается!`**

Comment: Почему `goto` не принимается? Вы сами себе ставите ограничения, а потом пытаетесь их героически обойти.

Comment: Без `goto` вам придётся заводить булев флаг, который будет показывать, не нужно ли выходить из внешней конструкции.

Comment: VladD, не хотел брать `goto`, потому что думал, что здесь есть какой-то особый подход. Ну и ещё пишут везде, что крайне не жедательно юзать `goto`

Comment: @АртурКлочко но городить странные решения вместо goto - еще менее желательно!

Comment: @АртурКлочко Обычно добавляют - "кроме как для выхода из глубоко вложенных циклов". Есть еще `setjmp/longjmp`, но это я бы вообще не рекомендовал трогать - уж очень крутое средство...

Comment: Не совсем в тему, но я рекомендую жестоко и со вкусом наплевать на тех, кто категорически против goto. Это догматики, вряд ли хорошо понимающие философию программирования. У данного подхода (у применения goto, а не у плевания) есть свои хорошие и плохие моменты, требующие отдельного обсуждения. И выход из глубоких конструкций через goto может быть хорошим решением.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, хорошо, ну тогда буду юзать `goto`, только попробую вариант с исключениями . Спасибо

Comment: Zealint , ну я так понял в `goto` основной риск- использование не объявленной переменной, ну или других данных

Comment: а почему нельзя всю такую конструкцию в отдельную функцию и из неё `return` ?

Comment: @АртурКлочко: Никакого риска уже давно нет. Компилятор просто не позволит сделать неправильно. http://ideone.com/yAFhLT

Comment: Я уже увидел, только что пробывал, спасибо, ещё раз!

Comment: @pavel `return`, имхо, самый правильный вариант, но это может не согласовываться с другой идеологией - единственного `return` в функции.

Comment: @VladD Структурировал холиварчик в комментариях. :) Если будут ещё подобные вопросы, можно будет избавляться. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Лирическое отступление

Позиция "goto не принимается" берётся из непонимания проблемы goto, и почему Дейкстра написал свой исторический документ, а Вирт изуродовал goto в Паскале.

Исторически противостояние с goto позникло на фоне перехода на структурное программирование. Проблема goto в том, что при использовании безусловных переходов *без ограничений* код превращается в неподдерживаемую лапшу, в которой невозможно понять, какой кусок выполняется после какого, и при каких условиях. В старых языках и при старых компиляторах с помощью goto можно было совершать невообразимые вещи: обходить инициализацию переменных, врываться внутрь циклов и вообще произвольных функций. Легко понять, что подобное использование goto встречало неприятие.

Структурное программирование решало эту проблему, превращая типичные использования goto в условные переходы и циклы. Все эти if, else, while, for, do и прочие, которые теперь есть во всех языках — не более, чем *паттерны использования goto* (если быть точнее, конструкции `if (a) goto b`) с синтаксисом на уровне языка.

Проблема в том, что структурное программирование эффективно решает не все реально возникающие проблемы. Осталось несколько красивых и эффективных паттернов, которые так и остаются во власти goto: быстрый выход из нескольких циклов, освобождение ресурсов при отстутвии RAII, переход по состояниям автомата и некоторые другие. В этом случае уже *использование структурного программирования превращает код в лапшу*, а код с goto остаётся чистым и понятным, если хорошо понимать эти паттерны.

Кроме того, проблема использования goto для входа в произвольный кусок кода давно неактуальна: современные компиляторы просто не позволят вам обойти инициализацию переменной или проделать какую-нибудь подобную шалость.

### Структурное программирование

Некоторые языки предлагают дополнительные конструкции: **именованные блоки** и параметризация break именами блоков (`outer: for { for { break outer } }`), выход из произвольного числа блоков заданием **числового параметра** (`for { for { break 2 } }`) и прочие костыли. В C++ этого всего нет.

У вас остаётся только традиционный костыль выхода из вложенных циклов/блоков — вынесение в отдельную функцию и **использование return**. Только учтите, что использование return где-то помимо конца функции тоже воспринимается как ересь ярыми адептами структурного программирования.

Если вы такой ярый адепт, то у вас один путь: вводить **дополнительные переменные**. По сути, вся идея противостояния goto зиждется на том факте, что любой код с goto можно преобразовать к коду без goto путём введения переменных.

```
void c()
{
    bool exitCase1 = false;
    switch (a)
    {
        case 1:
            switch (b)
            {
                case 1:
                    exitCase1 = true;
                    break;
            }
            if (exitCase1)
                break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Аналогично со вложенными циклами: везде добавляйте переменные и дополняйте код условиями выхода: `for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !exitFor; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 10 && !exitFor; j++) ...`.

Учтите, что подобный код с морем if и переменных для значительной части программистов будет выглядеть заметно сложнее, чем код с goto. Кроме того, подобный код менее эффективен: безусловный переход с помощью goto, очевидно, работает быстрее, чем многочисленные проверки на каждом уровне вложенности, особенно в случае циклов.

И упасите вас боги воспользоваться исключениями для выхода из цикла — это надругательство над языком, за которое вас посадят на кол и адепты, и противники goto. Исключения должны использоваться для обработки *исключительных ситуаций*, а не для управления потоком выполнения программы.

### Нормальное решение

Просто **используйте goto**.

Уже больше 40 лет прошло после структурной революции, пора расстаться со старыми слепыми религиозными взглядами и принять реальность такой, какая она есть. А в этой реальности до сих пор остаются задачи, которые эффективно решаются с помощью goto. Профессионалы должны знать паттерны правильного использования goto, а не прятать голову в песок и писать лапшекод из-за отживших свой век взглядов, которые насадили предки.

Впрочем, всегда следует стараться пользоваться возможностями языка, которые приходят на замену goto, если таковые есть. Например, если в языке есть выход из нескольких блоков с помощью break, то goto здесь не нужен. Если в языке есть RAII (конструкторы-деструкторы в C++) или конструкции для освобождения ресурсов (using в C#), то goto для освобождения ресурсов не нужен.

Comment: Круто, чё. Можно давать ссылку потомкам.

Comment: Ого, до меня дошло, что предыдущие ответчики имели ввиду под этими "статусными" переменными. Ну `goto`, так `goto`. Спасибо за ответ и Вам!

Comment: 1- Плюс за упоминание идеи: структурное программирование—паттерны использования goto, замороженные в синтаксисе языка. Как  кто-то сказал, что design patterns это bug reports для создателей языка программирования 2- *"Исключения должны использоваться для обработки исключительных ситуаций, а не для управления потоком выполнения программы."* —от языка зависит, например, `StopIteration`, `GeneratorExit` в Питоне. Конечно, существовал/существует? аргумент, что исключения вообще не должны быть использованы в С++ коде (Google).

Comment: @jfs Любопытно. Но питон здесь — скорее исключение, чем правило. Как я понял, исключения в этом случае обрабатываются особым способом, так что это типа хака. Да и аргументация в духе "вызывать проверку на окончание итератора медленнее, чем бросить исключение". Ну ОК, пусть быстрее. :)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант - при помощи исключений, хотя с точки зрения пуристов от C++ это плохой вариант.

Второй способ - заведение булевых флагов с их установкой и проверкой.

Именованные `break` в C++  пока не завели...

Comment: Исключений? В смысле `try` `catch` ...?

Comment: @АртурКлочко Именно. И `throw` тоже :)

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать и этот вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: ... не только плохой, но и жутчайше неэффективный.

Comment: VladD , почему?

Comment: @АртурКлочко: Ну не существует на текущий момент эффективных реализаций исключений. Разве что компилятор поймёт и уберёт его совсем, превратит в `goto`. А вы спрофилируйте, сами убедитесь.

Comment: Мг, ну я всё равно собирался попробовать, посмотрю, что выйдет. Юзать буду всё-таки `goto`

Comment: @VladD, про эффективность нужно думать тогда, когда она становится проблемой и не минутой раньше.

Comment: @ixSci с одной стороны - да. С другой - использование не по назначению, уже сомнительное удовольствие.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, это конечно так и есть, я уж пытался подобрать хоть какой-то аргумент, раз официальная рекомендация не использовать исключения для control flow не считается достаточно веской.