# Сравнение двух двухмерных массивов

Tags: c++

Нужно сравнить 2 двумерных массива на схожесть элементов. Если 1 элемент отличается, завершать цикл. Пытаюсь сделать, однако получается только завершить второй цикл, а первый продолжает работать.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a [2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int b [2][3] = {{1,3,3},{4,5,6}};
    for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j= 0;j<3;j++){
            if (a[i][j]!=b[i][j]){
                cout << "q" << endl;
                break;
            } else cout << "qq" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нетипичный выход из switch и for: выход из нескольких вложенных блоков и циклов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521543/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-switch-%d0%b8-for-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Замените `break` на `return 0;` :)

Comment: Попробуйте `goto`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a [2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int b [2][3] = {{1,3,3},{4,5,6}};
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        if (flag) {
            for(int j= 0;j<3;j++){
                if (flag) {
                    if (a[i][j]!=b[i][j]){
                        cout << "q" << endl;
                        flag = false;
                    } else cout << "qq" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: return не выход, потому что мне нужно применять эту проверку в приложении. Иду проверять goto

Comment: может еще попробовать bool flag = True

Comment: @Mkorny попробуй так, но намного легче сделать отдельную функцию и сделать return в нужный момент

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

В общем, послушал avp и решил прочитать про goto. Говорят вещь та еще(плохая). Но в итоге получилось так, как в принципе мне нужно. То бишь, если 1 элемент отличается, то цикл завершается. В версии hlghl немного заморочено, как я думаю. И она выводит сначала qq а потом q, вроде как, ну а надо что-то одно, сообщение о том, что либо эти массивы одинаковые, либо нет. Вот моя версия, если что, подправьте, пожалуйста :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a [2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int b [2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j= 0;j<3;j++){
            if (a[i][j]!=b[i][j]){
                cout << "q" << endl;
                goto link;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "qq";
    link:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А чем вам в таком случае Harry с кго `return 0;` не угодил? Тот же результат.

Comment: А тем, что мне нужно использовать такую проверку в приложении, а именно в методе класса, а он немного void, и значения вроде бы не возвращает...

Comment: А если написать не `return 0;`, а просто `return;`? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag = true;
for (int i = 0; flag && i < 2; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; flag && j < 3; j++) {
    if (a[i][j] != b[i][j])
      flag = false;
  }
}
cout << (flag? "qq" : "q") << endl;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]